# How do I get python3 in the command line to point to the version I installed with homebrew?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

This is what I see in terminal:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ python3
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

There is no `python3` binary at `/usr/local/bin/`.

There is a file called `python3` at `/usr/bin/` however.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put it in the front of your path. If you are using bash, do this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then either source ~/.bash_profile or open a new terminal. Then try `which python` and it should show you the version in this directory. Or type in `python --version` and it will report "Python 3.7.7".

Answer (score 0):

Which version did you install?

Run `brew info [python-package]` and you should see something like this (for example I installed `python@3.8`, so I ran `brew info python@3.8`)

```
If you need to have python@3.8 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Just run the line and restart terminal, it should be working.

Comment: You have the right idea. I simply closed terminal and opened it again so that the terminal could read the Path variable again after the install.

Answer (score 0):

I closed terminal and then reopened it and it fixed the problem. Now typing python3 opens the python interpreter.